# How to sort a list with order predefined by another (bigger) list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Suppose that we have two lists.

- list1 defined the standard order.
- list2 is the one we need to sort (list2 is smaller than list1, but all elements of list2 contains in
  list1)

How to sort list2 use the ordering defined by list1?

For exampple:

> list1 = ['x', 'y', 'a', 'c', '11', 'de']

and

> list2 = ['c', 'y', 'de', 'x']

So that sorted_list2 should be

> sorted_list2 = ['x', 'y', 'c', 'de']

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The intuitive way is

```
sorted_list2 = sorted(list2, key=list1.index)
# ['x', 'y', 'c', 'de']
```

However, if your `list1` is very long then this will not be very efficient. Better is to turn `list1` into an efficient hashtable of indices first:

```
list1_dict = dict((k, i) for (i, k) in enumerate(list1))
sorted_list2 = sorted(list2, key=list1_dict.get)
# ['x', 'y', 'c', 'de']
```

(note: I refer to the functions `list1.index` and `list1_dict.get` directly
because it works, but you can put any method or lambda here that takes the element as input and returns a sorting key as output (e.g. `lambda x: list1.index(x)`), if you need to be a bit more complex)

Comment: probably `{k: i for (i, k) in enumerate(list1)}` would be better than `dict(<gen exp>)`

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach than sorting would be to iterate through `list1` and output items that are in `list2`. Convert `list2` to a set first for efficient lookups. This improves the average time complexity to *O(n)*, where *n* is the length of `list1`, from the time complexity of calling `sorted` on `list2`, which costs *O(n log n)*, where *n* is the length of `list2`:

```
set2 = set(list2)
sorted_list2 = [i for i in list1 if i in set2]
```

If there can be repeating items in `list2`, you can use `collections.Counter` instead of a set to keep track of the counts of each distinct item in `list2` to achieve the same linear time complexity:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['x', 'y', 'a', 'c', '11', 'de']
list2 = ['c', 'y', 'de', 'x', 'y']

counter2 = Counter(list2)
sorted_list2 = [i for i in list1 for _ in range(counter2[i])]
```

And `sorted_list2` would become:

```
['x', 'y', 'y', 'c', 'de']
```